# Moving OBX above NTE

Tags: mirth

I have successfully managed to move NTE after PID to the end of the message using the code

```
var nteGroup = getSegmentsAfter(msg,msg.PID,'NTE',true);
for (var i = nteGroup.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
delete msg.children()[nteGroup[i].childIndex()];
msg.insertChildAfter(msg.OBX[msg.OBX.length()-1],nteGroup[i]);
}
```

But having difficulty moving the NTE below each OBX group.

Currently it is

```
PV1
NTE
ORC
OBR
NTE
NTE
NTE
NTE
OBX
```

Would like it to be

```
PV1
ORC
OBR
OBX
NTE
NTE
NTE
NTE
NTE
```

Happy to share `HL7` message if needed

Answer (score 0):

Referencing https://www.mirthproject.org/community/forums/showthread.php?t=220406

The code solution is to do the following:

```
var nteGroup = '';
var nte_count = 0;

for each( seg in msg.children()) {
if(seg.name == 'NTE')
{
nteGroup += seg.toString();//may need to add '\n'
delete msg['NTE'][nte_count++];
}
msg += nteGroup;//may need to add '\n' on front and/or back
}
```

Comment: Should be `seg.name()`